# double click on RecyclerView item not trigger onInterceptTouchEvent when talkback is on

Tags: android, onclick, touch-event, talkback

I have a problem event talkback double clicks. Below code , onInterceptTouchEvent is not triggered
when any item's isClickable field is true.Do you have any solution for this problem? (I must set clickable to true on item)

```
      val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL ,false)
    recyclerView.adapter = object : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
            val t  = TextView(this@MainActivity)
            t.isClickable = true
           return MyViewHolder(t) {

           }
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
                holder.bindView()
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
           return 60
        }
    }
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(object : RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
        override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(r: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onTouchEvent(r: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent) {

        }

        override fun onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept: Boolean) {

        }
    })
```